# Nexus or Artifactory for OSGI based applications

Tags: nexus, artifactory, obr

We are developing an OSGI based Soa Solution and about to set up a maven repository manager. I read that Nexus has OBR support and Artifactory does not seem to have - firstly, is this true? Secondly, since this is my first OSGI application development I am not really sure what are the disadvantages of choosing a repository not having OBR support in this case?

Thanks and regards,
Priya